# Failed to install Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am installing doxygen using

```
 sudo apt-get install doxygen
```

but getting following unmet dependencies. I tried with google but not getting proper solution for same.

I am getting this while run above code:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 doxygen : Depends: libclang1-3.6 (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am also tried with `sudo apt-get install -f` but no solution.

Comment: try to install clang / llvm (version >= 3.2). Probably better not to try version version 6 (at the moment) as I've seen some reports about problems using this version in combination with doxygen.

Comment: OK I will try and let you know

Comment: @Nik when there are multiple people who commented use the `@` with the name to address the intended commenter (otherwise the commenter might not see it)

Comment: @albert sorry, I forgot to mention that. Problem is solved thanks for your response.
I have decrease some of my libraries to lower version using 'sudo aptitude'